# How to pass parameters correctly via bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have the following problem: I have a widget that displays a list of profiles with the date of birth. I also have a widget with many filters. Through FAB, I open a window where you can select the date of birth limits to display people with only the desired date of birth. I also have Bloc's for the list of users and for the filter.

How can I pass two age parameters to load a new list with other users matching the filter? I tried adding an event from the filter widget to the user widget before and after I do navigation.pop, but I didn't succeed. Can someone please explain how I can do this?

And Yes, I repeat again, the screen with the selection of filters is separate because there are many parameters.

Main Widget (screens/users.dart):

```
child: Scaffold(
          body: _buildListUsers(),
          floatingActionButton: FadeTransition(
              opacity: _fabHideAnimation,
              child: ScaleTransition(
                  scale: _fabHideAnimation,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: OpenContainer(
                    closedBuilder: (_, openContainer) {
                      return FloatingActionButton(
                        elevation: 2.0,
                        hoverElevation: 0.0,
                        highlightElevation: 0.0,
                        child: Icon(Icons.filter_alt_outlined),
                        onPressed: openContainer,
                      );
                    },
                    openColor: Colors.blue,
                    closedElevation: 5.0,
                    closedShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                    closedColor: Colors.blue,
                    openBuilder: (_, closeContainer) {
                      return SearchFilter();
                    },
                  )))),

Widget _buildListUsers() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider<UsersBloc>(
            create: (_) => _usersBloc,
          ),
          BlocProvider<FilterBloc>(
            create: (BuildContext context) => FilterBloc(),
          ),
        ],
        child: BlocConsumer<UsersBloc, UsersState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is UsersError) {
              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  content: Text(state.message),
                ),
              );
            } else if (state is UsersLoadingMore) {}
          },
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is UsersInitial ||
                state is UsersLoading && _users.isEmpty) {
              return _buildLoading();
            } else if (state is UsersLoaded) {
              _users.addAll(state.usersModel);
              BlocProvider.of<UsersBloc>(context).isFetching = false;
              _hideFabAnimationController.forward();
              return _buildCard(context);
            } else if (state is UsersLoadingMore) {
              BlocProvider.of<UsersBloc>(context).isFetching = true;
              return _buildCard(context);
            } else if (state is UsersError) {
              return Container();
            } else if (state is FilterLoaded) {
              // _users.clear();
              // _users.addAll(state.usersModel);
              // BlocProvider.of<UsersBloc>(context).isFetching = false;
              // _hideFabAnimationController.forward();
              // return _buildCard(context);
              return Container();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Filter Widget (screens/filter.dart):

```
filterWidget() {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Filter"),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[50],
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                flex: 15,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: SafeArea(
                    child: mainFilterWidget(),
                  ),
                )),
            Material(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  BlocProvider.of<FilterBloc>(context).add(FilterUpdated(
                      selectedDateFirst.toString(),
                      selectedDateSecond.toString()));
                  // Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: SafeArea(
                    left: false,
                    right: false,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: null,
                      elevation: 0,
                      disabledColor: Colors.transparent,
                      child:
                          Text("Search", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

In filter bloc i do like this:

```
if (usersBloc.state is UsersLoaded) {
      firstDate = event.firstDate;
      lastDate = event.lastDate;
      yield FilteredUsersLoaded(
        _mapUsersToFilteredUsers((usersBloc.state as UsersLoaded).usersModel,
            event.firstDate, event.lastDate),
      );
    }


  _mapUsersToFilteredUsers(
      List<User> users, String firstDate, String lastDate) async {
    final mList = await apiRepository.getUsers(
        page: 1, firstDate: firstDate, lastDate: lastDate);
    return mList;
  }
```

Comment: add a little bit code for better help

Comment: thanks for reply, i did it

Comment: I do not see you catch FilteredUsersLoaded anywhere. Besides, it is good practice to remove unnecessary code (like animations etc), so it is easier for the other one to understand the code and see the issue